# How to connect to Elasticsearch by PySpark without cert verification?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

Is there a way to connect to Elasticsearch (https://IP:9200) by PySpark without certificate verification?

I didn't see any settings for this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html

Curl works fine:

```
curl -iv --insecure --user admin:password --noproxy '*' https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9200
*   Trying xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9200...
* Connected to xx.xxx.xx.xxx (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) port 9200 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /opt/conda/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=dev-1; CN=dev-1-es-http.es-dev.es.local
*  start date: Jul  9 00:47:04 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Jul  9 00:57:04 2021 GMT
*  issuer: OU=dev-1; CN=dev-1-http
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9200
> Authorization: Basic abc==
> User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 544
content-length: 544

<
{
  "name" : "dev-1-es-hot-2",
  "cluster_name" : "dev-1",
  "cluster_uuid" : "444",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.8.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "123",
    "build_date" : "2020-06-14T19:35:50.234439Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.5.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
* Connection #0 to host xx.xxx.xx.xxx left intact
```

My last try:

```
reader = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .option("es.port", "9200") \
    .option("spark.es.net.http.auth.user", "admin") \
    .option("spark.es.net.http.auth.pass", "password") \
    .option("es.net.ssl", "true") \
    .option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "true") \
    .option("es.net.proxy.https.use.system.props", "false") \
    .option("es.nodes", "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
```

Ends with:

```
: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverClusterInfo(InitializationUtils.java:348)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.cfg$lzycompute(DefaultSource.scala:225)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.cfg(DefaultSource.scala:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.lazySchema$lzycompute(DefaultSource.scala:229)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.lazySchema(DefaultSource.scala:229)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.$anonfun$schema$1(DefaultSource.scala:233)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.schema(DefaultSource.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:448)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:240)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:432)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.mainInfo(RestClient.java:745)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverClusterInfo(InitializationUtils.java:338)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1356)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1174)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1408)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:819)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1189)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.CommonsHttpTransport.doExecute(CommonsHttpTransport.java:685)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.CommonsHttpTransport.execute(CommonsHttpTransport.java:664)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:116)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:110)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory$TrustManagerDelegate.checkServerTrusted(SSLSocketFactory.java:76)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1510)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1340)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 62 more
```

I also trying to provide keystore/truestore without results.

Comment: I am facing similar issues, did you manage to resolve ?

Comment: I did not. But finally I connect to Elasticsearch by creating jks file (I use https://keystore-explorer.org/ for that). File Should be on all Spark nodes.

Then:
        .option("es.net.ssl.truststore.location", ELASTIC_OPUS_JKS) \
        .option("es.net.ssl.truststore.pass", ELASTIC_OPUS_JKS_PASS) \

Comment: Ok thanks for the information! I'll try this way. One question, how does this thing work ? I have to create a jks file and what then ? I need to add a certificate to it ? In this case, which certificate do I have to add ? The one that is on the es server ? Sorry for the questions but I don't have a lot of experience in this field.

Comment: This tool that will discover certificates base on url that you can provide. And then it will create jks file base on that.

Comment: Ok so I think I'll have to talk with the team that handles the es servers. Thanks again, my issue was that they told me that the mutual authentication with a certifcate was not necessary but the fact that you (and other users) needed a truststore means that we have to follow this way.

Comment: Just to inform you that adding the trustore was the right choice and now my spark job can communnicate with the ES server! I think it would be great for other users that have the same issue if you post your own answer to the question with the solution you adopted. If you don't mind I can answer myself to your question, I just don't want to "steal" the answer from you :)

Comment: Yes. You can write it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you, but in Java. As already stated in the comments below the question, the issue is that we need to use the server certificates in order to complete the TLS handshake.

I used the [tool suggested by lubom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67438404/how-to-connect-to-elasticsearch-by-pyspark-without-cert-verification?noredirect=1#comment125108075_67438404)and added the certificates to a .jks truststore, put a password then finally I added the truststore to all the worker servers of the spark cluster.

Then added the following properties

```
        conf.put("spark.es.net.ssl.keystore.location", "<truststore path>");
        conf.put("spark.es.net.ssl.keystore.pass","<truststore password>";
```

In this way I was able to communicate with the ElasticSearch Server.

P.S. If this answer is useful don't thank me, but @lubom which solved my issue  in the comments thread below the question! I answered the question (after asking permission) just to clearly put how we both solved our common issue.